# Computing sum of squared differences between to images in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm having trouble getting my code to work in Matlab. I'm trying to compute the sum of square differences between two images that are the same dimension. I am getting an exceeding matrix dimensions error, and I just want confirmation that this is the way to go about computing the SSD? Here is the code I have so far:
    clear
    clc
    close all

```
imgL = imread('pentagon_L.png');
% image(imgL);
imgR = imread('pentagon_R.png');
% image(imgR);

imgL2 = double(imgL);
imgR2 = double(imgR);

% The height and width need only be computed once since images are the same
% size.
[height, width] = size(imgR2);

% maxShift = 0.08;
shiftPixels = 5;

for i = 1 : height
    for j = 1 : width
        ssd(imgL2,imgR2) = sum(sum((imgL2(i,j) imgR2(i+shiftPixels,j+shiftPixels)).^2))/(height*width);
    end
end

imshow(ssd)
```

Comment: 1. You forgot a `-` in the loop. 2. Your loop goes from 1 to `height`, but inside you try to access `height+shiftPixels` which exceeds the image size. 3. The is no need for a loop, for that, you can substruct the images just with `-`, but have to make sure they are the same size (just like in your loop).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually would like to implement the SSD to compare small regions centered at a pixel. Would you help me with that?

Comment: Create a matrix `M` of the same size as the images that is 1 in the region centered around the pixel and 0 elsewhere. Then the following code will calculate the sum of squared differences for just this region: `sd = (imgR1 - imgR2).^2 .* M; ssd = sum(sd(:));`.